# How to stream video OR send a video file

Tags: html, node.js, video, streaming, live-streaming

I am developing a web app which will be able to live stream or at least send video files which both user can access at same time.
I am using HTML5 and node.js

Answer (score 0):

Is this a linux machine? I would recommend ffmpeg's ffserver for streaming. It gives you many configuration options and runs stable on my machine here. Like that you could convert your streaming source to the format you need for your player.

Comment: no i am using windows but i would like to develop it on cross platform and since i am new to this can u please elaborate about ffserver

Comment: Hi, i guess ffserver is not available for windows. But you could also look at http://code.google.com/p/rtmplite/ which uses python.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of streaming, we can do one thing
If you have a server machine then upload that audio/video on that server machine.
You can upload in Node.js with the help of [formidable module](https://github.com/felixge/node-formidable).

And since HTML5 allows video and audio so no need of flash player, just make sure the audio/video will be compatible in all browsers (for videos, mp4 works in all major browser Check this link for more information on [HTML Videos](http://www.w3schools.com/html/html5_video.asp)). And after upload send a command(video location) from server to all clients which plays the video from the desired location in javascript

```
<html>
  <body>
    <video id='videoPlayer' width="320" height="240" controls="controls">
       <source id='mp4Source' src="movie.mp4" type="video/mp4" />
       <source id='oggSource' src="movie.ogg" type="video/ogg" />
    </video>

<!-- You MUST give your sources tags individual ID's for the solution to work. -->

    <script>
socket.on('videoLocation',function(data)
{playVideo(data);});

function playVideo(location){

      var player = document.getElementById('videoPlayer');

      var mp4Vid = document.getElementById('mp4Source');

      player.pause();

      // Now simply set the 'src' attribute of the mp4Vid variable!!!!
      // (...using the jQuery library in this case)

      $(mp4Vid).attr('src', location);

      player.load();
      player.play();
}
    </script>
  </body>
</html>
```